# Finder folders gone?

Tags: macos, finder

My `Favourites` sidebar has gone in `All My Files` in `Finder`:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcWFY.png]

There is a thing which you can pull out from the side like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogr6m.png]

but it doesn't have any of my `Favourites` in. But I have got them (it shows them in the `Preferences`):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGwAP.png]

If I open a folder/disk, it does show them:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgrEx.png]

How do I get my `Favourites` back? I have Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting finder by hitting CMD + OPTION (ALT) + ESC -> Choose Finder and click restart.

If this doesn't work try performing a "Repair Disk Permissions" inside Disk Utility, and reboot.